# Retrieve facebook users realtime data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to track facebook application users whatever they are doing on facebook, for e.g watching a video or visiting someone's page and show it in the application.

Comment: the answer is simple: no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, but only for Mark Zuckerburg and crew.**